# Azure's default routing table and IP blocks owned by UK Ministry of Defence

Tags: azure, routing, azure-networking

I have created a VM that is connected to a vnet located in West Europe. There is nothing special about the VM, its routing configuration, or anything else, and nothing special about the vnet.

When looking at the VM's NIC effective routes I see the address prefixes `25.33.80.0/20` and `25.41.3.0/25` which seem to come from the default system route table. A quick whois revealed that these blocks are owned by the UK Ministry of Defence.

The next-hop type is set to "none", which means packets destined to any of these addresses will be dropped. However, this still makes me curious. Also because I couldn't find anything related in the official documentation.

Also, it doesn't make a difference if I create the VM in Australia, US or anywhere in Europe!

Why do these routing entries exist? And what purposes do they fulfill? Any idea?

[image]

Answer (score 0):

I've also got these in mine - would really like to know why they are in there - even thought the next hop is none